# HttpConnection truncating messages in Sony Ericsson W580

Tags: java, java-me, midp

I've been having a problem while using `HttpConnection` with a Sony Ericsson W580.

The response to my http requests is `application/octet-stream`, and I'm sending a quite large array of bytes.

In this mobile phone however, it is consistently being cut down to 210 bytes...

I've tested the MIDP application in a large number of different mobile phones, using different mobile carriers and wi-fi, and no other mobile has shown this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Entirely my fault...

How I was reading the stream:

```
while(true){
    int bytesRead = stream.read(tmpBuffer);
    // if -1, EOF
    if(bytesRead < 0)
        break;

    (...)

    // WRONG LOGIC !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // if we read the last chunk of data, and found EOF
    if(bytesRead < tmpBufferArrayLength)
        break;
    // WRONG LOGIC !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
}
```

See the part between the "wrong logic !!!" comments? I was assuming that if read(tmpBuffer) could not fill the tmp buffer entirely, it was because EOF was being reached. The [API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) does not guarantee this at all: it just states that EOF is signaled by a read(tmpBuffer) returning -1.

I didn't see this before because all the mobiles (and emulatores) I'd tested were being able to fill completely the buffer at every call.